# Name both suppliers that make one part in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with a basic query that I can't exactly figure out.
So I have a Suppliers table and a Parts table. In the Parts table, the supplier numbers are listed along with the part number. In the supplier table, the supplier number is listed with the supplier name. I want to get part numbers and supplier names for parts that are made by two different suppliers.

```
SELECT s.supplier_name, p.part_num
FROM supplier s, part p
WHERE s.supplier_num = p.supplier_num
GROUP BY s.supplier_name, p.part_num
HAVING COUNT(p.part_num) > 1;
```

This is what I have so far, but it only returns one result per part that is listed twice rather than two, and I don't know how to get both.

Comment: I would be surprised if `COUNT(p.part_num)` were ever greater than 1 since you're grouping on both `supplier_name` and `part_num`. In fact that would suggest to me that you have non-unique values for `supplier_name` in your `supplier` table -- or possibly non-unique values for the combination of `supplier_num`/`part_num` in your `part` table.

Answer (score 2):

Use a derived table to get the part_num s that have more than one supplier. Then `join` it to the other tables to get the desired result.

```
select s.supplier_name, p.part_num
from supplier s
join part p on s.supplier_num = p.supplier_num
join (SELECT part_num
      FROM part 
      group by part_num
      HAVING COUNT(distinct supplier_num) > 1) t
on p.part_num = t.part_num
```

Comment: Hm, it seems like using this gave me no results. Any ideas why?

Comment: then there are no part nums with more than 1 distinct supplier. it would also help if you post some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your query would work to get a list of parts made by more than one supplier. The reason is that you're grouping on `supplier_name`. You might try something like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT s.supplier_name, p.part_num
         , COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY p.part_num ) AS supplier_cnt
      FROM supplier s INNER JOIN part p
        ON s.supplier_num = p.supplier_num
) WHERE supplier_cnt > 1;
```

Here I am using `COUNT(*)` as a window (analytic) function instead of as an aggregate. Using `part_num` in the `PARTITION` of the window function will get the count of suppliers per part. This does assume that there are no duplicates in the `supplier` table or `part` table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `exists` to check whether the same part by a different supplier exists

```
SELECT s.supplier_name, p.part_num
FROM supplier s
JOIN part p ON s.supplier_num = p.supplier_num
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM part p2 
    WHERE p2.supplier_num <> p.supplier_num -- different supplier
    AND p2.part_num = p.part_num -- same part
)
```